# Corona "tick" issues - addEventListener

Tags: event-handling, lua, coronasdk

I've been trying to write out a custom tick using the Corona SDK (using Lua).  The key seems to be these "eventListeners," but I'm also trying to get them to work with classes.  right now i have this class "World" set up.  I'm trying to add an EventListener to my "tick" function, but Corona is telling me I can't do it.

```
function World:tick()
--player:tick()
--camera:tick(player.x,player.y)
--for i=0,monsters.length do
--      monster[i]:tick()
    if(rwalk) then
        mainGroup.x = mainGroup.x-10
    elseif(lwalk) then
        mainGroup.x = mainGroup.x+10
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",tick)
```

Error: Runtime error: assertion failed!
stack traceback:
        [C]: ?
        [C]: in function 'assert'
        ?: in function 'getOrCreateTable'
        ?: in function 'addEventListener'
        ?: in function 'addEventListener'
        C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\lua\test game\main.lua:337: in main chunk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me. Should work for you:

```
World = {}

function World:tick()
    print "Hello!"
end

display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", World.tick)
```

All you were missing was to specify the function using `World.tick` instead of `tick`.

Comment: oh.  that worked thanks!  but now i can't access any of my world object's properties in there.  say i add the line (and initialization to my World:new()):


self.test = true


anywhere in that function.  it gives me an error that "test" is nil. is there anyway to do an event listener while retaining the object and all of it's properties?

Comment: If you accept my answer and open a new question along with sample code, I'll be happy to look at it. :)

Comment: oh okay.  i accepted your answer but i'll start a new question.